# Recursive sequence of renewal type : when does one term dominate them all?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $(b_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be an increasing sequence of non negative real numbers.

Let $(u_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be recursively defined by $u_0 =1$ and

$$u_{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} u_{k} b_{n-k}$$

Find a sufficient condition (as weak as possible, ideally also necessary)  on the sequence $(b_n)$ under which the first term of the sum, $k=0$, gives the main contribution:

$$u_n \sim b_n$$

as $n \to \infty$.

I am able to prove that $b_n = n!$ works, and I have guesses of what could be a mild condition but not of a necessary and sufficient condition.

(Warning : cross posting with MSE, I think this is more appropriate to MO on second thought).

Comment: An obvious necessary condition is $b_{n-1}/b_n\to 0$ and I believe this is also sufficient, though it could be quite tedious to actually show it.

Comment: This is weak indeed ! What kind of proof do you have in mind ?

Comment: I think one just has to study the recursion in more detail. For example, the overall structure of the solution is $u_n = \sum c b \cdots b$, where the indices of the $b$'s add up to $n$ in each term. If one could now prove a suitable estimate on the coefficients $c$, that might get it done (or I could just be wrong...).

Comment: Thanks Christian. For the moment I think I can imagine how to do if $b_n/b_{n-1}$ diverges at least as a power of $n^{\delta}$ for some arbitrarily small $\delta$, but I have no idea how to get further.

Comment: I was just guessing around, of course, it could well be that this is actually close to where the borderline is and my condition is too weak.